# Integrating $\frac1{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Having trouble integrating $1/\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are positive constants.

So far I've completed the square and put it in the form 
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{a(x+(b/a)^2)+((4ac-b^2)/4a)}}
$$ 
and am wondering if I remove the 'a' from outside the first bracket can I simply integrate using the arctan formula? or is it something more complicated involving multiple substitutions

Comment: Completing the square followed by trig/ hyperbolic sub or [integral table](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ15/integ15.html).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: ... Or Euler substitution. :)  Good one @DavidH

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

For a handy reference for integrating things involving $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$ see http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ15/integ15.html

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a}x+\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2+d^2}}$,

with $d = \sqrt{\dfrac{4ac-b^2}{4a}}$, and assume $a > 0$, and $4ac-b^2 \geq 0$.

And next we make the substitution: $\sqrt{a}x+\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{a}} = d\cdot \tan \theta$.

Comment: Could you expand on why we make the substitution d⋅tanθ?

Comment: but where is the tan coming from?

Comment: I'm still working on it. At the moment I'm having trouble clearing up the algebra from changing the dx to dθ

Comment: It just seems to have gone in a bad circle for me. During the substitution the sec^2 cancelled and I was left with the integral of dθ/d*sqrt(a)

Comment: Perhaps its the dx to dθ thats thrown me. We have √ax +b/2√a =d⋅tanθ. I got dx=(dsec^2θ/√a) dθ

Comment: Thats what I did from √ax +b/2√a =d⋅tanθ. Then separated it out to get dx so I could replace it from the integral of dx/sqrt((d*tanθ)^2+d^2)

Comment: Think I got it! Give me a sec to write it